# How to know which element is in overflow

Tags: javascript

I want to know which element is in overflow, e.g code is below:

```
const isOverflown = ({
    clientWidth,
    clientHeight,
    scrollWidth,
    scrollHeight,
  }: any) => {
    return scrollHeight > clientHeight || scrollWidth > clientWidth;
  };
```

Whit this function above and the target element I can know when parents have overflow problems. But how to know which of children element make that overflowing?

Comment: Some rules need to be set before being able to answer. What if multiple adjacent children are overflowing? Should they both be returned, or only the first one? What about depth? For example, if a `div` is overflowing, but it's overflowing because of an `img` inside it. Should it return the `div`, the `img`, both? Also, could you be kind and post a demo with HTML and CSS which we can play around with?

Comment: @blex, thanks for your question.
Well, the parent has a with, but some of the children can on any resolution with paddings or margins example can make overflow, how to know which of that children make that?